# UIButton and setImage: not working consistently - inconsistent

Tags: iphone, uiview, uibutton

I have a UIButton on a UIView. I want to programatically figure out which image to display inside the button when the view is displayed. I have overriden the drawRect method in the UIView and used a setImage to display the desired image. However, when the view displays, sometimes it draws the desired image, and sometimes it does not. I have to touch anywhere in the view for the image to show up in the button. Please help !

Here is the drawRect method for the view.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Everything is wired up IB correctly. I don't understand why the image appears/doesn't appear consistently. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really don't want to override drawRect.

The proper thing to do is implement a UIViewController, and override [viewWillAppear:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear:).

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
};
```

Answer (score 2):

groundhog has the [right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219852/uibutton-and-setimage-not-working-consistently-inconsistent/1219985#1219985), but I would just like to explain what is actually happening with your code, and why it works some of the time.

The `drawRect` method gets called every time the system wants your view object to display itself on the screen. Setting the button image in the `drawRect` method *will* change the button image, but since the system is already in the process of drawing to the screen, you will not actually see the change until the *next* time the views need to be redrawn. In this case, when you touch somewhere else in the view.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately, this code is part of a larger project with another developer. I CAN'T change the current UIView to a UIViewController. Can I change the button image in another fashion? (Like maybe before adding the subview of the owning ViewController? for example, before I issue [masterViewController.view addSubview:myView];

Comment: Absolutely. Setting a button image programmatically is *usually* done in `viewWillAppear`, but if you are using a different initialization method, you can do it there instead. As long as you don't put any initialization code in the `drawRect` method, you should be fine.

Comment: BINGO! This worked perfectly! Thanks very much to you and groundhog. You guys are G-R-E-A-T. (Also, sorry for the accolades on this forum, but, I didn't want to drop the thread without expressing my appreciation.)

Comment: Glad to hear it! Be sure to give groundhog the accepted answer. That will wrap things up nicely. Good luck with the rest of your project :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately, this code is part of a larger project with another developer. I CAN'T change the current UIView to a UIViewController. Instead, I changed the button image in another fashion. I changed the button's state just prior to adding the UIView to the subview of the owning ViewController. ie: I issued the

```
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Just prior to adding my UIView as a subView. ie:

```
[masterViewController.view addSubview:myView];
```

obviously, myButton is part of myView. Thanks for the assist.